# Windows ContextMenu C++ with Shortcuts in Selection

Tags: c++, windows, contextmenu, shortcut, shell-extensions

I'm having difficulty obtaining the list of selected files in my implementation of a ContextMenu when the target of my right-click is a shortcut. The global memory handle returns a list containing only the shortcut item, and doesn't seem to know about any of the other items I've selected.

I've noticed this behavior in a number of 3rd party apps as well, including Notepad++, WinRar and UltraEdit.

What is the correct way to obtain a list of selected files when the target of the right-click is a shortcut? This isn't an issue for the file compression functionality baked into Explorer (right click > send to > compressed zipped folder).

Edit: here is a small snippet of my current method. `pida->cidl` becomes 1 when the target is a shortcut, otherwise it is the correct number of items I've selected:

```
CStgMedium me; 
pDataObj->GetData(&fe, &me); 

LPIDA pida = reinterpret_cast<LPIDA>(me.hGlobal); 
for(UINT i = 0; i < pida->cidl; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What interfaces you implementing?

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about `IContextMenu` interface here? If so, you should do it like that (mistakes possible, I'm writing without compiler):

```
Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder, IDataObject *pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID){

    FORMATETC fetc = { CF_HDROP, null, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
    STGMEDIUM stgm;

    pdtobj->GetData(&fetc, &stgm);
    UINT count = DragQueryFile(stgm.hGlobal, 0xFFFFFFFF, null, 0);
    char filename[255];

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
        DragQueryFile(stgm.hGlobal, i, filename, 255);
        // Here do something with i-th filename
    }
}
```

I omitted error checking for simplicity.

Comment: Sorry I meant `IShellView`, there is no dragging/dropping of any files or folders. I'm making the following calls at the moment:

     `CStgMedium me;
     pDataObj->GetData(&fe, &me);
     LPIDA pida = reinterpret_cast<LPIDA>(me.hGlobal);
     UINT num = pida->cidl;`

The pida->cidl value is the one that is changing; in the scenario above, this value becomes 1 when the target of my right click is a shortcut. If the target is not a shortcut it becomes the actual number of items selected.

Comment: "This isn't an issue for the file compression functionality baked into Explorer" - that doesn't mean that it's known to general public how to do it. Microsoft has the tendency to reserve some APIs to their use only.

Comment: That's true, I'm hoping that isn't the case for this scenario, hopefully someone can confirm =(

Comment: Any hints on what you are currently doing? A code snippet of how you try to get to the list of selected items? I expect that there is one documented way to do it (that you now use), and if it doesn't work then we are in the wilds - only internal, undocumented ways will work.

Comment: It's pretty much the snippet I posted in my first comment, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Have you tried using `DragQueryFile` instead of mapping the memory on your own using `reinterpret_cast<LPIDA>(me.hGlobal)`? It is not drag-and-drop related, I know but this function apparently is capable of more than it's name would suggest.